# Parse mixed xml in C# Linq to Xml

Tags: linq-to-xml

The xml element below

```
<text>this is some text <content><link attr="someattr">text to appear in link</link></content> . this is the end of the text</text>
```

needs to transform to

```
<p>this is some text <a attr="someattr">text to appear in link</a> . this is the end of the text</p>
```

I have a method that takes in "content" element as parameter and returns the "a" element. I cannot figure out how to display the text from "text" element and the link at the same time.

Comment: I you need to *transform* a text - perhaps Linq-to-Xml is not the right way to go. You should look into [RegularExpressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595.aspx)

Comment: this is not text but xml. I have only shared a snippet of the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```cs
var xml =
    @"<text>this is some text <content><link attr=""someattr"">text to appear in link</link></content> . this is the end of the text</text>";
var text = XElement.Parse(xml);
//change <text> to <p>
text.Name = "p";

var content = text.Element("content");
var link = content.Element("link");

//change <link> to <a>
link.Name = "a";

//move <a> to be after <content>
content.AddAfterSelf(link);

//remove <content> tag
content.Remove();

//print result
Console.WriteLine(text.ToString());
```

Comment: This actually works but when the xml contains more than 1 "content" elements, then I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Instead of removing element using content.Remove(), I tried text.Elements("content").Remove(); which did the trick. I also ran the previous code in a foreach loop to add the "a" elements appropriately.